# How to monitor the tabs with specific prefix url?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension which would do "some codes" after I get to and load some websites. For example, the prefix is "https://stackoverflow.com/". I want to monitor the urls of the tabs. The "some codes" would be executed after "https://stackoverflow.com/~" webpage loaded. How could I do it? I have no idea especially about how to monitor the tabs?
I will be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do so the question is not answerable, but I guess you can start with the documentation for *content scripts*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Content Script** to execute code after the URL you monitor opens and the page loads, however you have to mention URLs you monitor in the **Matches** part of Manifest.json file.

Read thorough the Chrome Extension documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions)